# Unable to update entity in an MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am trying to update the User entity in my MVC application, however when I press 'Save' on the cshtml all the UserModel model parameters are null in the HttpPost actionresult. Any ideas why this is? When loading the Details.cshtml, the User is not null and all the data is there.

**UserController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        UserModel user = _userService.GetSingle(u => u.Id == id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(UserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _userService.Update(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Details.cshtml**

```
@model Core.Models.UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firstname</label>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firstname)">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite normal as if you didn't put any `Html.Editor, Html.TextBox`, .... inside your form.

You can try with  `@Html.EditorForModel()`  inside your Html.Beginform

Comment: Ahh, complete oversight! Should have spotted this myself!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not exposing your model properties through the view.

However, I don't know what you're going to save since it doesn't contain any edit fields.

Anyway, try adding in your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ModelProperty)
```

And do this for all the properties of your model. I don't know if there are other solutions, but I believe that this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute of your text input is empty; try setting it to 'model.Firstname'. The names of your inputs need to match the properties of your model in order for them to be bound in the action method.